# Implementing a lock-free stack with OpenMP: compare-and-swap

Tags: openmp, atomic, c11, compare-and-swap

I'm writing a C library on which I want to optionally support concurrence by using OpenMP (so that one may compile it serially if the compiler does not support OpenMP). I'd like to use a lock-free stack implementation.

I thought about using C's `stdatomic.h` for the stack, but seems that [until a few weeks ago, GCC couldn't use `_Atomic` with OpenMP](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65467), so this would complicate portability. Clang 3.8 seems to handle atomics with OpenMP correctly, but still this would not be the best choice since there's no need to keep it atomic when compiling without OpenMP (thus serially).

I seem to need to use a compare-and-exchange operation when popping from the stack, and I couldn't find any information regarding compare-and-exchange on OpenMP. Is there any way to implement a lock-free stack solely with OpenMP?

My code so far (works with clang):

```
struct lfstack_node {
  void *value;
  struct lfstack_node *next;
};

typedef struct lfstack {
  _Atomic(size_t) size;
  _Atomic(struct lfstack_node *) head;
  _Atomic int aba;
} *lfstack_t;

// ...

void *lfstack_pop(lfstack_t stack) {
  if(stack) {
    atomic_fetch_add(&stack->aba, 1);
    struct lfstack_node *node, *next;
    do {
      node = atomic_load(&stack->head);
      if(!node) {
        break;
      }
      // ABA problem here if not handled correctly
      next = node->next;
    } while(!atomic_compare_exchange_weak(&stack->head, &node, next));

    atomic_fetch_sub(&stack->aba, 1);
    if(node) {
      int zero = 0;
      while(!atomic_compare_exchange_weak(&stack->aba, &zero, zero)) {
        continue;
      }
      void *value = node->value;
      free(node);
      return value;
    }
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

Comment: You can compile your code in a different compilation unit, so that it does not need to pass through OpenMP's front-end. Then, use the stack interface in such a way that the _Atomic is not exposed. Another option is using [GCC atomic built-ins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html)